# Can you help - i have an issue in my VBA which is causing an error as the VBA believes the current row = 0

Tags: excel, vba

Can anyone help, i am fairly new to VBA, i have the below code related to a next button within a userfrom:

```
Private Sub cmdPrevious_Click()

If currentrow = 4 Then
    MsgBox "You are viewing the first record!"
    Exit Sub
End If

currentrow = currentrow - 1

UnitNumberTextBox = Cells(currentrow, 1)
```

However when i get to UnitNumberTextBox = Cells(currentrow, 1) the VBA thinks the currentrow = 0?
When the form intialises i have preset the currentrow to 4 so im confused

If anyone is able to advise it would be must appreciated

Thanks in advance

Comment: How and where do you declare `currentrow`?

Comment: Hi Scott, please see below

Comment: ```Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim currentrow As Long
currentrow = 4````

Comment: When declared in another sub it does not persist.   It will need to be declared as a public static variable.

Comment: Please read about variable scope: https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/variable-scope.html

Comment: Please edit your question and provide all clarification **in the question**. Nobody wants to read through all the comments to find out what you're really asking.

Comment: Also, at the top of your module on a line by itself above any code, add "Option Explicit", which will add the very annoying, but life-saving step of refusing to compile unless your variables are explicitly declared. Soooo many errors are like this, or typos in variable names. Always adding "Option Explicit" will save your sanity. Trust me.